# Gradient border-left on pseudo selector :after

Tags: css

I'm trying to put the same gradient on the :after pseudo selector that is on the anchor.

```
<a class="atlas-tabs" href="">Gradient</a>

.atlas-tabs{ 
   background: #c53a73; /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c53a73 0px,#af3b6b 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0px,#c53a73),    color-stop(100%,#af3b6b));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c53a73 0px,#af3b6b 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c53a73 0px,#af3b6b 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c53a73 0px,#af3b6b 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(top, #c53a73 0px,#af3b6b 100%);
   color: #FFF;
   display: block;
   padding: .9em 0em .9em 1em;
   position: relative;
   text-decoration: none;
   width: 11.33em; 
}
.atlas-tabs:after{
   content:""; 
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px; 
   position: absolute; 
   right: -.3em; 
   top: 0;
   border-top: 25px solid transparent;
   border-right: 0 solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
   border-left: 5px solid #b33b6d;
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8nzeK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the CSS triangle using border trick, you can't apply gradient to it. So you have to find another way to create the triangle. One of the possible ways is to use a `skew` transform to create the triangle. Then you can just apply the same background `linear-gradient` to the `:after` element correctly. Here is the code details:

```
.atlas-tabs:after{
  content:""; 
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em; 
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) skew(30deg,30deg);
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #c53a73 0px,blue 100%); 
  z-index:-2;
}
```

**NOTE**:

- I changed the color stops a little to make it distinct because the color stops you used looks too similar (nearly solid background to me).
- I just use `-webkit-` prefix, so please test the demo on Chrome or Opera. You can edit the demo to run OK on other browsers.
- This solution requires trial and error, so to find out the values for `width` and `height`of the `:after` element, you may have to reduce/increase and try it. Of course If you are good at maths, I believe you can calculate those values.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/8nzeK/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you could use  gradient too to draw your arrow: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8nzeK/1/)**

```
.atlas-tabs:after {
    content:"";
    width:3em;/* tune this */
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 0;
    background:/* tune degrees to your needs */
        linear-gradient(-80deg, white 50%, transparent 50%), 
        linear-gradient( 80deg, transparent 50%, white 50%)
}
```

A more obvious example of the code ahead rescaled with different colors: http://jsfiddle.net/8nzeK/2/